# Class design for self-linked classes with generic pointer type

Tags: c++, boost, interprocess, allocator

I am currently modifying a complex class that has nodes **pointing to themselves** just like linked lists or graphs. I want it to be used in shared memory using **boost::interprocess** functions. Now I am looking for the way to redesign it such that it stays generic and involves least changes.

```
template< class T >  
class node {  
  public:  
    T data;  
    node* prev;  
    node* next;  
};
```

The redesign should make use of the **boost::interprocess::allocator** allocator in order to implicitly use the relative smart pointers of type **boost::interprocess::offset_ptr**. I thought it should involve a second template parameter like

```
template< class T, class alloc_type = std::allocator< node< T > > >  
class node {
  public:  
    T data;  
    typename alloc_type::pointer prev;  
    typename alloc_type::pointer next;  
};
```

which of course doesn't work due to cyclic dependencies just as with references.
I hope a can get some help from a C++ class template pro on the best way to implement it. I had a look at the boost shared memory enabled containers but they are solving it in a rather complicated manner that involves several external classes.

Joh

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a node class in a doubly linked list. Is this because you simplify the example code that far, or is this indeed what that class looks like? If the latter, why not use `std::list` and pass a custom-allocator?

Comment: It is because of simplification, it is in fact a complex tree class. BTW: with std::list implementations do not seem to guarantee that they will use the allocator::pointer because the standard says that it is equivalent to a raw pointer. This is why boost::interprocess provides a set of standard containers.

Answer (score 1):

> which of course doesn't work due to cyclic dependencies just as with references.

Yes, that will not work, because the type `node` is being defined and it's not yet complete, but you're passing it to `allocator` as type parameter. Hence the problem!

Also, `node` is a class template, but when you're passing it to `allocator` you're not providing type argument for `node`. But dont worry, even if you pass, it will not work since type `node` is not yet complete (as I said before).

---

Besides that you've another problem,

```
alloc_type::pointer prev;  
alloc_type::pointer next;
```

Here you need `typename` as

```
typename alloc_type::pointer prev;  
typename alloc_type::pointer next;
```

Comment: And... `std::allocator< node<T> >` as `alloc_type`?

Comment: Yep, sorry for the missing typenames and the T, I was minimizing the code it to show the basic problem: it is a cyclic dependency of class templates.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am looking for a strategy to resolve this mutual dependency and hoped that someone had something in mind.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the allocator class belongs to the container, not the element. I realize that, for intrusive containers like yours, they can be the same. But, can we factor it back out?

How about:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T, class alloc_type >
struct nodePtr {
    typedef typename alloc_type::pointer pointer;
    typedef alloc_type allocator;
};


template< class T >
class node {
  public:
    typedef nodePtr<node<T>, std::allocator<node<T> > > pointer;
    // OR: typedef nodePtr<node<T>, my_allocator<node<T> > > pointer;
    T data;
    pointer prev;
    pointer next;
};

node<int> n;
```

Of course, I can't figure out how to pass `std::allocator<>` to `node<>`, but maybe you don't need that. Do you mind specifying your allocator's name in the middle of `class node`?

Or maybe, we could make your allocator the default allocator for `nodePtr`?

```
// untested
template <class T> class node;
template <class T, class alloc_type = my_allocator<node<T> > >
class nodePtr { /* ... */ };
template <class T> class node {
    public: typename nodePtr<T> prev;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Rob. The problem is that the nodes are wrapped in a container class that will receive the allocator via the constructor. This is like it is done in boost and necessary, if the allocator is not stateless. However, I think I can pass a void allocator that can be converted into any type allocator. So I need to build a linked node data structure within this container class in a generic way.